# Can't change target API in AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I create a new virtual device in AVD Manager, in the target drop down menu I only have two options available: API levels 8 and 17 (2.2 and 4.2.2), although I have installed all APIs in between, with all their subcomponents. What's more, if I do select 4.2.2 the OK button is disabled.

How can I add target APIs to the AVD Manager? Aren't they directly linked to the SDKs I've got installed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They aren't tied to the SDK versions that you have installed; the available AVD versions are tied to the system images that you have installed via the SDK manager.

For example, you can see ARM EABI v7a System Image, Intel x86 Atom System Image, and MIPS System Image under Android 4.2 (API17) in the SDK manager.

Comment: All of the system images are marked as installed, 2.2 through 4.2.2 with all three versions. Why don't they show up in the AVD Manager?

Comment: For some reason you made me think about restarting Eclipse. I haven't done this to a program or my computer after an installation since Windows XP... Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 12):

Just encountered the same thing. Try restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to check your path to SDK location, it might be pointing to other SDK location where only Android 4.2.2-API Level 17 & Android 2.2-API Level 8 is installed.

You can do so by going to Window -> Preferences (in your eclipse), in Preferences goto Android, in Android you will see the SDK Location. Browse & change SDK Location to the SDK location where your Android SDK tools is installed. For Eg.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Comment: Finally a working solution. Felt silly coz the sdk path is the wrong one. Ty

Comment: @MosesAprico Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Android SDK Manager 
1) ensure the path- points to location u installed your SDK

2)Check Android 4.2.2(API 17) checkBox

3)Press Install button